# Passing Json Data to MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-4

Here I need to pass Json object to the controller.But i have a problem in the MVC JsonResult controller area. I have no idea how to get those objects there. In **ItemQtys** there are multiple values.

My Code:

```
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function (e) {

        var itemQtys = [];

        var currentQty;
        $('input.input-qty').each(function (itm) {
            currentQty = $(this).val();
            if (!isNaN(currentQty) && currentQty != '') {
                currentQty = parseInt(currentQty);

                itemQtys.push({
                    ItemId: $(this).attr('data-id'),
                    Qty: currentQty
                });
            }
        });

        var data = {
            UserId: $("#CustomerName option:selected").val(),
            DeliveryInstructions: $('#DeliveryInstructions').val(),
            ItemQtys: itemQtys
        };



        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Orders/SubmitCustomerOrder",
            contentType: "application/; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: data,
            async: false,
            success: function (msg) {
                if (msg.length > 0) {
                    $.each(function (response) {
                        //$("#Result").text(response.text);
                    });
                }
            }

        });

    });
```

MVC Controller: (I want to get the values to here)

```
 public JsonResult SubmitCustomerOrder(OrdersModels model, int? id)
    {

        return Json(new {  });

    }
```

My model:

```
  public class OrdersModels : DbContext
{
    public class CustomerOrders
    {
        public int CustomerOrderId { get; set; }
        //public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime DeliveryDate { get; set; }
        public string DeliveryInstructions { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public int Customer_Supplier_CustomerSupplierId { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public List<OrderItems> OrderItemList { get; set; }

    }

    public class OrderItems
    {
        public int OrderItemsId { get; set; }
        public int Products_ProductId { get; set; }
        public int CustomerOrders_CustomerOrderId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public Guid ModifiedBy { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: your parameters do not match up to the data you are passing. I don't see your model in the JSON you are posting....

Comment: again, still the parameters do not match your controller POST action. What I am saying is that you are not serializing the form which is bound to the model OR you are not constructing the model structure on the client side to then be POSTED to the controller action.

Answer (score 0):

For this scenario you must add a custom model binder for OrdersModels  and create your model from  httprequest

```
    public class OrderModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
         var userId=request.Form["UserId"];
          //ToDo
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Model does not have any properties that can be used to bind - you need something to assign values to which match the schema of the posted data.

If you change your controller method to accept UserId, DeliveryInstructions and ItemQtys as values, your routing should work - you can then use these values to create your object server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a JavaScript object which has same fields in `CustomerOrders` class and pass it as a JSON object to controller on submit as below.

```
var customerOrders= {};
// fill the object.

$.ajax(
{
    url: 'Controller/SubmitCustomerOrder/',
    data: JSON.stringify({customerOrders: customerOrders, id : id }),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        // success
    },
    error: function () {
       // error
    }
});
```

Controller can be as below.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SubmitCustomerOrder(CustomerOrders customerOrders, int? id)
{
    return Json(new {  });
}
```

Please refer following post for more information.

[Pass Complex JavaScript Object to MVC Controller](http://sarangasl.blogspot.com/2014/01/pass-complex-javascript-object-to-mvc.html)

It illustrates how we can pass complex javascript objects to MVC controller.

Thanks !